# WooCommerce - Shipping plugin ignored

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've written a plugin that adds a custom shipping method to WooCoomerce.

It seems to be intermittently NOT returning shipping prices.

On the cart page, the shipping estimator works fine; then, when you click through to checkout,  it will INITIALLY display all the results (from cheapest to fastest) but on refresh, with correct GUEST billing address, it returns nothing; debugging shows that it does not even call the plugins' shipping calculator or 'enabled' function check. It just says that there are no shipping options for Australia (if this is the only shipping option activated)

Have tried contacting the Woo guys, but nada.

**EDIT:**

Lessons learned.

**Firstly, the big one:** WooCommerce uses transients - it caches your shipping results. You can reset these in WooCoomerce settings, system status->tools  ***Extra edit: Lastest WooCommerce version lets you turn this off! .. But only if you are shopping as administrator ..***

**Secondly:** Once the above was out of the way, it simply turned out that I was reading in the posted address details incorrectly, and my plugin was returning 'false' and knocking itself out of the running. Big thanks to xDebug and PHP Storm ..

**Thirdly:** As an aside, I have also hooked the plugin's instantiation to the woocommerce_shipping_init, as Woo *NOW* recommends. Check out their revised docs at the [shipping method API page](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/shipping-method-api/)

Answer (score 2):

You should at least show us your code :-)

I bet there is something related to shipping address that is removing the shipping options.

Comment: Any news on this question? 
Do you still need help? 
Can you share you code or solution?

Answer (score 0):

If the initial page loads fine, but when address info is updated it doesn't respond correctly it may be a javascript issue.  I'm working on a custom shipping plugin right now myself, and when any shipping details are changed it fires an event that updates the shipping results through AJAX.  Posting a link to the checkout page, or looking for javascript errors on the front end might be very helpful.